# Fine tuning freezing weights nnUNet

Tags: pytorch, transfer-learning, unet-neural-network, fine-tuning

Good morning,
I've followed the instructions in this github issue:

https://github.com/MIC-DKFZ/nnUNet/issues/1108

to fine-tune an nnUNet model (pyTorch) on a pre-trained one, but this method retrain all weights, and i would like to freeze all weigths and retrain only the last layer's weights, changing the number of segmentation classes from 3 to 1.
Do you know a way to do that?
Thank you in advance

Comment: "to freeze all weigths and retrain only the last one", you probably meant "freeze all weights except the last layer, and retrain the last layer only", right ?

Comment: Yeah exactly, sorry for the inaccuracy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To freeze the weights you need to set `parameter.requires_grad = False`.

Example:

```py
from nnunet.network_architecture.generic_UNet import Generic_UNet

model = Generic_UNet(input_channels=3, base_num_features=64, num_classes=4, num_pool=3)

for name, parameter in model.named_parameters():
    if 'seg_outputs' in name:
        print(f"parameter '{name}' will not be freezed")
        parameter.requires_grad = True
    else:
        parameter.requires_grad = False
```

To check parameter names you can use `print`:

```
print(model)
```

which produces:

```
Generic_UNet(
  (conv_blocks_localization): ModuleList(
    (0): Sequential(
      (0): StackedConvLayers(
        (blocks): Sequential(
          (0): ConvDropoutNormNonlin(
            (conv): Conv2d(128, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
            (instnorm): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (lrelu): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01, inplace=True)
          )
        )
      )
      (1): StackedConvLayers(
        (blocks): Sequential(
          (0): ConvDropoutNormNonlin(
            (conv): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
            (instnorm): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (lrelu): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01, inplace=True)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
  (conv_blocks_context): ModuleList(
    (0): StackedConvLayers(
      (blocks): Sequential(
        (0): ConvDropoutNormNonlin(
          (conv): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (dropout): Dropout2d(p=0.5, inplace=True)
          (instnorm): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (lrelu): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01, inplace=True)
        )
        (1): ConvDropoutNormNonlin(
          (conv): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (dropout): Dropout2d(p=0.5, inplace=True)
          (instnorm): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          (lrelu): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01, inplace=True)
        )
      )
    )
    (1): Sequential(
      (0): StackedConvLayers(
        (blocks): Sequential(
          (0): ConvDropoutNormNonlin(
            (conv): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
            (dropout): Dropout2d(p=0.5, inplace=True)
            (instnorm): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (lrelu): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01, inplace=True)
          )
        )
      )
      (1): StackedConvLayers(
        (blocks): Sequential(
          (0): ConvDropoutNormNonlin(
            (conv): Conv2d(128, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
            (dropout): Dropout2d(p=0.5, inplace=True)
            (instnorm): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (lrelu): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01, inplace=True)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
  (td): ModuleList(
    (0): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2), padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  )
  (tu): ModuleList(
    (0): Upsample()
  )
  (seg_outputs): ModuleList(
    (0): Conv2d(64, 4, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
  )
)
```

Or you can visualize your network with `netron`:

https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron